# Googleapis - Code 400 - API Key not valid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, search

Receive the error below when trying to setup Youtube Search, below is a snip of the command I am using (Key hidden for security purposes) Please see below troubleshooting steps already taken

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&key=Axxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx

**** Error Message from dev console ***

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "API_KEY_INVALID",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "youtube.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Troubleshooting Steps

1. Created a new project in Google Cloud
2. Setup new API key in the cloud console and restricted zone to my websever using star.domainname.star, including restricting API to using YouTube Data API v3
3. Copied API Key into JScript code as shown above and cleared Internet Cache and went to the website - still saying API key not valid.

I am reaching out to the community to see what the issue would be, I have watched videos from google support and other forums and nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

the &q= {seach string} at the end of the url was missing

Obvious mistake now after walking away from it and coming back to look at the code.

Working great!